# How to redirect using `getServerSideProps` with props in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

After a user signs in, I use `router.push()` to redirect the user to their profile page. I am using `getServerSideProps()` for authentication right now. When the redirect happens, the props don't seem to be fetched and I have to refresh the browser myself to call gSSR. Is this behavior normal or is there a way to fix it?

#### Demonstration - Updated

##### login.js

```js
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

export default function Login({user}) {
  const router = useRouter();

  // invoked on submission
  async function submitLoginForm(email, password) {
    const user = await signIn(email, password)
    const username = await getUsernameFromDB(user);
    router.push("/" + username);
  }

  return ( ... );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
  const user = await getUserFromCookie(req);
  if(user === null) {
    return {
      props: {}
    }
  }
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: `/${user.username}`,
      permanent: false
    }
  }
}
```

##### [username].js

```js
export default function Profile({user, isUser}) {
  // Use isUser to render different interface.
  return ( ... );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({params, req}) {
  // The username of the path.
  const profileUsername = params.username
  // Current user.
  const user = await getUserFromCookie(req);
  ...
  if(user !== null) {
    return {
      props: { 
        user: user, 
        isUser: user !== null && profileUsername === user.username
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    notFound: true
  }
}
```

The cookie is set in the `_app.js` using the Supabase auth sdk.

```js
function MyApp({Component, pageProps}) {
  supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange( ( event, session ) => {
    fetch( "/api/auth", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers( { "Content-Type": "application/json" } ),
      credentials: "same-origin",
      body: JSON.stringify( { event, session } ),
    } );
  } );

  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code from `login.js` doesn't make a lot of sense. You should never call `useRouter` outside of React component and expect it to work properly. It is called `useRouter` because it is a custom React hook. I would recommend that you install the package `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` and integrate it into your Eslint configs to make sure that this doesn't happen again to you.

Comment: @ViktorLuft Oh I discarded some valuable information, the snippet for `login.js` is inside the React component.

Comment: Could you please update your post, so it contains all relevant code?

Comment: @ViktorLuft Done. Will this be enough information?

Comment: Still missing, how you set the cookie for the user and when `foo` gets invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you update your `_app.js` like that:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  // make sure to run this code only once per application lifetime
  useEffect(() => {
    // might return an unsubscribe handler
    return supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(( event, session ) => {
      fetch( "/api/auth", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: new Headers( { "Content-Type": "application/json" } ),
        credentials: "same-origin",
        body: JSON.stringify( { event, session } ),
      });
    });
  }, []);
  

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Also, please make clear what is happening. E.g. my current expectation:

- Not authenticated user opens the "/login" page
- He does some login against a backend, that sets a cookie value with user information
- Then `router.push("/" + username);` is called
- But the problem now: On page "/foo" he sees now the Not-Found page instead of the user profile

  - Only after page reload, you see the profile page correctly

If the above is correct, then it is possible the following line is not correctly awaiting the cookie to be persisted before the navigation happens:

```js
const user = await signIn(email, password)
```

It could be that some internal promise is not correctly chained/awaited.

As an recommendation, I would log to the console the current cookie value before calling the `router.push` to see if the cookie was already saved.